# replace the last value of a line

Tags: python, python-2.7

I wish to replace the last value of this line
`V1 N0005 0 0.1` by the value which is changing continuously i.e., I have taken the last value of this line into a variable as `v1val` and has been increasing it using while loop. But I am unable to replace it.
Please help me with the command which would replace the value
My code snippet is

```
v1val+=0.1
f=open("Draft2.net",'r+')
for x in f:
    if x.startswith('V1'):
        V1=float(x.split(' ')[-1])
        x.replace(float(V1[-1]),float(v1val))
f.close()
```

The value is being incremented along with another snippet which is in while loop.

Comment: Does this code raise no error?

Answer (score 0):

Replace this

```
x.replace(float(V1[-1]),float(v1val))
```

with this

```
x = x.replace(float(V1[-1]),float(v1val))
```

`string.replace()` does not modify the string (in fact, python strings are immutable). Instead, it returns a new string that can then be assigned to a variable.

You'll also need to write the new version of x back to the file with `f.write()`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to replace the last value (I use `0.2` as an example):

```
In [11]: s = "V1 N0005 0 0.1"

In [12]: " ".join(s.split()[:-1] + ["0.2"])
Out[12]: 'V1 N0005 0 0.2'
```